# Trouble Calling A Tab Bar Controller From App Delegate

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble launching a tab bar controller from App Delegate. However, the controller is called correctly from a different view controller, so I know it's working. This is the code I used in the view controller:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.tabBarController)
self.view.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

While that worked for the view controller, that didn't work for App Delegate, so after researching I found the following:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let tabBarController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.tabBarController) 
self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

That didn't work either. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? If it matters, please note the tab bar controller doesn't have its own class, I designed it in Storyboard.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should move your code to the `SceneDelegate` and do some changes concerning the initializiation of `window`.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBarController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.tabBarController)
    
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```